# How do i make global search return a case by searching a value stored in a custom text field?

Tags: custom-field, configuration, global-search

Recently I was presented with a bug in which Global Search doesn't return any cases when I search for a value stored in a custom Text field inside the case. In my tests to replicate the error I, as a sys admin, was able to perform the search, whereas logged in as a consultant, I was not.

I read that, aside from searchable custom fields, in order for a field to be searchable, it has to be marked as read and edit in the object settings on the profile. I checked on both profiles and they are. I also checked the record type for the consultant and it seems ok too.

Now, when I'm logged in as a consultant and I wrap the search around quotation marks, it does return, but according to the area supervisor, this isn't the normal behaviour, as they were able to just paste the string on the global searchbar, hit enter and it returned the specific case they were looking for. This is the behaviour that occurs when I'm logged in as an admin.

I'm at loss on this one. I can't think of a solution for this occurrence, as the field, being a Text type, according to the Salesforce Documentation should be searchable, the consultant profile has access to the field, it is in its layout, and the record type is configured accordingly.

I'm sorry in advance if my questioning seems like a beginners one. In fact, I just completed my 3rd month working as a Salesforce dev, and I'm still getting the hang of it. Also, thanks in advance.

PS: I proposed to the area supervisor that they use the quotation marks around the string they're looking for, but it was denied.

---

tl;dr: I'm unable to return a case by a value stored in a custom Text field, even though it should be searchable, and the profile has access to the field.

---

**Edit:** since I was unable to find a solution to this issue, I contacted the Salesforce Support and they told me that this is a known bug indentified in the Summer '21 release, as you all can see in the link below:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002JRg5QAG

As of today (06/Aug/21), there are only 2 possible workarounds to this issue: use the quotation marks around the searched terms, as I had already identified it before, or in Salesforce Classic use the Exact Phrase option. This should return the records you were looking for, but were unable to find.

Comment: is this in lightning? Are there a lot of records that match this string?

Comment: Yes, it's in Lightning. Since it's an input field, there may be some typos, but mostly yes, it should return more than one record

Comment: The [quotation marks](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.search_unified_results.htm&type=5) might be reducing the results that match so that [search results crowding](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.search_crowding_considerations.htm&type=5) doesn't come into play. How many case records are being returned for the user who doesn't see the record? I'd also be interested if the user who can't see interacts with that record (view it, maybe edit it, etc) whether they start seeing that record now?

Comment: No case records return. I updated a record as the case owner and tried searching for it again, but it also didn't return any case records.

Answer (score 0):

There may be something else going on as well, but to clarify: custom text fields can be indexed but are not indexed by default. You must open a support case to have create the index for that field. I had to do this recently for a reporting reason. I would think it should make search more reliable & faster as well, but I have not had that use case exactly.

See [Developer Documentation on Indexes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_indexes.htm)
The line is `To create custom indexes for other field types, including standard fields, contact Salesforce Customer Support.`

Also, FYI you can check if a given field is indexed by going (in Lightning) to Setup > Object Manager > Object Name > Fields & Relationships > then look at the INDEXED column for a check mark.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did say something silly. Yes, the Text fields aren't automatically indexed. But according to this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.search_fields_case.htm&type=5 they should be searched on when I use Global Search given that the profile has access to it, right? I mean, for me it does. But for the consultant, it doesn't, even though both of us have access to it.

Comment: There's a difference between *search index* and *database index*. Custom fields of the appropriate type are always search indexed, but are not database indexed unless you check certain options or contact support.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for the clarification. I do need to refine my platform phraseology so as to be more precise.